# Compress base64 string in python and extract it in PHP

Tags: php, python, base64

I'm sending a base64 string compressed with zlib in Python, converted to base64, sent to a PHP page where it will be extracted.

I'm having trouble with this. How would I do this?

Right now I have:

python

```
compressor = zlib.compressobj(wbits=(16+zlib.MAX_WBITS))
compressed = compressor.compress(str)
compressed += compressor.flush()
```

php

```
*POST deccoded here, b64data is the output*
$b64data = zlib_decode($data);
```

I left out the part where I decode from base64. The php code throws and error about invalid data at the zlib function.
`zlib_decode(): data error`

Comment: um. ... `base64_decode($b64data)` maybe...  [base64_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) , just guessing.

Comment: Yeah I left that part out. I'm not having trouble decoding. It throws an error about invalid compression at the zlib function.

Comment: Your code doesn't contain the base64 de-/coding. Maybe try this first with an uncompressed string to drill down the cause of problem.

Comment: `It throws an error about invalid compression at the zlib function` that would have been nice to know, you may want to add that to the question.

Comment: Using `wbits=(16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)` creates a gzip-header instead of the zlib header for `wbits=zlib.MAX_WBITS`. I don't know if PHP can cope with that.

Comment: PHP has to have gzip included. Most of the time it is, but you can check for it with ```phpinfo()```.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I messed up and the problem wasn't with the zlib function.

Long story short I used to encode the data twice on the Python side but changed it to only encode once and never removed the extra `base64_decode` from the PHP.

Thanks for the help guys.